# Type initializer exception ikvm weka from c# winRT

Tags: c#, weka, ikvm

I'm working on an windows 8 app, I'm using weka.dll and ikvm from my c# code.
I keep having type initializer java.nio.charset.standardCharset
The source is from IKVM.OpenJDK.util. As for the inner exception it's from mscorlib.

```
kmeans = new weka.clusterers.SimpleKMeans();
        weka.clusterers.ClusterEvaluation eval = new weka.clusterers.ClusterEvaluation();            
        kmeans.setNumClusters(numCluster);
        kmeans.setMaxIterations(nbrItr);
        kmeans.setPreserveInstancesOrder(true);
        Data = new weka.core.Instances(new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.FileReader(filePath)));
```

If i try to retreive data numInstances it works but then when i use the data to build my cluster i get an exception here:

```
kmeans.buildClusterer(Data);  //exception              
eval.setClusterer(kmeans);
eval.evaluateClusterer(Data);
```

More details about the exception:

```
System.TypeInitializationException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233036
  Message=The type initializer for 'java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets' threw an exception.
  Source=IKVM.OpenJDK.Util
  TypeName=java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
  StackTrace:
       at java.util.zip.ZipFile..ctor(File file, Int32 mode)
       at java.util.zip.ZipFile..ctor(String name)
       at IKVM.Internal.VirtualFileSystem.Initialize()
       at IKVM.Internal.VirtualFileSystem.GetVfsEntry(String name)
       at IKVM.Internal.VirtualFileSystem.GetBooleanAttributes(String path)
       at IKVM.NativeCode.java.io.Win32FileSystem.getBooleanAttributes(Object _this, File f)
       at java.io.Win32FileSystem.getBooleanAttributes(File )
       at java.io.File.isDirectory()
       at java.io.File.toURI()
       at IKVM.Internal.AssemblyClassLoader.MakeResourceURL(Assembly asm, String name)
       at IKVM.Internal.AssemblyClassLoader.AssemblyLoader.FindResources(String name)
       at IKVM.Internal.AssemblyClassLoader.<GetResourcesImpl>d__0.MoveNext()
       at IKVM.NativeCode.ikvm.runtime.AssemblyClassLoader.getResource(ClassLoader classLoader, Assembly assembly, String name)
       at ikvm.runtime.AssemblyClassLoader.getResource(ClassLoader , Assembly , String )
       at ikvm.runtime.AssemblyClassLoader.getResource(String name)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(String name)
       at weka.core.Utils.readProperties(String resourceName)
       at weka.core.Capabilities..ctor(CapabilitiesHandler owner)
       at weka.clusterers.AbstractClusterer.getCapabilities()
       at weka.clusterers.SimpleKMeans.getCapabilities()
       at weka.clusterers.SimpleKMeans.buildClusterer(Instances data)
       at App1.Clustering.kMeans.ClusteringKmeans()
       at App1.Views.ClusteringPage.Clustering_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

  InnerException: System.InvalidOperationException
       HResult=-2146233079
       Message=The API 'System.Exception.get_TargetSite()' cannot be used on the current platform. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248273 for more information.
       Source=mscorlib
       StackTrace:
            at System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicILGenerator.GetTokenFor(RuntimeMethodInfo rtMeth)
            at System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicILGenerator.Emit(OpCode opcode, MethodInfo meth)
            at IKVM.Internal.CodeEmitter.RealEmitOpCode(OpCode opcode, Object arg)
            at IKVM.Internal.CodeEmitter.OpCodeWrapper.RealEmit(Int32 ilOffset, CodeEmitter codeEmitter, Int32& lineNumber)
            at IKVM.Internal.CodeEmitter.DoEmit()
            at IKVM.NativeCode.sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.FastConstructorAccessorImpl..ctor(Constructor constructor)
            at IKVM.NativeCode.sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newConstructorAccessor0(Object thisFactory, Object constructor)
            at sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newConstructorAccessor0(Constructor )
            at sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newConstructorAccessor(Constructor c)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.acquireConstructorAccessor()
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Object[] initargs, CallerID )
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(CallerID )
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(CallerID )
            at sun.nio.cs.FastCharsetProvider.lookup(String )
            at sun.nio.cs.FastCharsetProvider.charsetForName(String charsetName)
            at java.nio.charset.Charset.lookup2(String )
            at java.nio.charset.Charset.lookup(String )
            at java.nio.charset.Charset.forName(String charsetName)
            at java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets..cctor()
       InnerException:
```

Comment: The type initializer exception is quite often thrown from a static constructor / initialization of a static type member. Looking at (1) the inner exception and (2) its stack trace should provide more information as to the cause. Please add that information to you question.

Comment: I added the information, but I think the varible "Data" remains null, is there something i've missed or i should add while retreiving instances from arff file?

Comment: I found [this SourceForge mailing-list page](http://sourceforge.net/p/ikvm/mailman/ikvm-developers/?viewmonth=201401) which suggests to me that what you are asking for might not be possible.  Quote: "To be honest, I think it's pretty hopeless, unless you use a *very* limited subset of Java *and* are willing to put a lot of time into it."

Comment: So the problem is in ikvm, can't use it in windows store app !